# Why the buttons are hiding behind the leaflet map... How to bring them forward?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, leaflet

I have written the html code to put some responsive buttons over the leaflet map. The buttons are hiding behind the map and not showing. How to bring them forward ?

This is the map[I want to put buttons over this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ2zE.png)

Buttons should look like this[Buttons should look like this over the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8xcE.png)

Please tell me what to do ?? ..My code is as under;

```
 <div id="map">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 mt-3">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <label class="d-lg-inline d-none">Zoom To Location</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 mt-lg-3 mt-0 ml-lg-4 ml-0 filter">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <label class="my-0 d-lg-inline d-none">FILTERS</label><br>
                        <a href="search" class="btn btn-warning mr-2">Criteria</a>
                        <a href="search" class="btn btn-warning">Satellite</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-9 mt-lg-3 ml-lg-5 ml-0 d-flex justify-content-start aoi">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <label class="my-0 d-lg-inline d-none">Define Area of Interest</label><br>
                        <a href="search" class="btn btn-warning mr-2">Draw</a>
                        <a href="search" class="btn btn-warning mr-2">Coordinates</a>
                        <a href="search" class="btn btn-warning">Upload</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(map);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the position of the container div (which contains the buttons and input fields) to "absolute" so that it is positioned relative to the map, and give it a high z-index (which makes it show above it rather than behind it). You can do so as follows:

```
<div class="container position-absolute" style="z-index: 1;" >
```

You also have to set the position of its parent container (the map div) to relative. You can do so as follows:

```
<div id="map" class="relative">
```